# Tomcat HTTPS Enable fail with self signed cert

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

I created a self sign certificate as shown below:

[image: Created self-signed cert as shown below]

Here is the command i Used:

```
keytool -genkey -v 
-keystore C:\softwares\apache-tomcat\KeyStore\selfcert.keystore 
-keyalg RSA -storepass XXXX -validity 360
```

I updated the server.xml to as below:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/xml" compression="on"
keystoreFile="C:\softwares\apache-tomcat\KeyStore\selfcert.keystore"
keystorePass="XXXX" maxThreads="150" port="8443"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
proxyPort="443" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

When I run the server, I am getting below error:

```
Feb 06, 2018 12:29:06 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase handleSubClassException
SEVERE: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler instantiation failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
```

I have referred multiple forums and tried multiple things, commenting few listeners and few others things but nothing worked. Please guide me.

Comment: why do you give for the CN field, your name, instead of an FQDN (www.mywebsite.com) ?

Comment: There is more to that error message. Can you please post the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

i see more problematic places

1) your command kyetool should contents followed parameter:

```
 -alias my.domain.cn
```

See too:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

2) in the server.xml you have protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol". 
 You don't wrote which version of Tomcat you used.
But it is better the non blocking conector or APR to use( from config  tomcat 8 documentation).
Maybe is org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol not available on your system?

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - non blocking Java connector
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol - the APR/native connector.
```

You can leave off the protocol parameter. Tomcat search for native library in the PATH environment variable.
[See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.htm**l)

**UPDATE**

*1) keytool*
The option -alias is not required (yes you are right EJP). It is used as a default alias "mykey". But if you want to generate a second certificate you MUST use a different alias.
In my experience, however, self-signed certificate is rejected by eg Oracle Web Service if the qualified name = hostname is not used

*2) IO*
because I don't know which operating system (probably Windows) and which versions of Tomcat, Java you use, I assume the Tomcat 8 or 9.
From version 8.5, org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol is not in distrubution. The solution is to use

```
`org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`.
or
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol
```

For the previous versions:
You can also check for yourself which protocol is available for your system.
In directory $CATALINA_HOME/lib call

```
jar tvf tomcat-coyote.jar | grep org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio
```

The output shows classes for NIO you can use.
Or you can refrain from defining a protocol:

> then the implementation used by Tomcat is chosen automatically.

say Tomcat.

Comment: There is nothing in your citation about `-alias my.domain.cn`. All the examples use `-alias tomcat`. Using a non-blocking connector has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Please look again at the question. "Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8443]]". This is the direct issue but creating a keystore is also wrong.

Comment: Please look again at your sources and tell us where it says to use an alias based on the domain name. It doesn't. You made it up. Please also tell us how changing to a different connector solves this problem.

Comment: @EJP. 
1)Do you have a problem with a key as domain name? Yes, it can be different. But there must be some, and Madhu Pathy has none!
 
2) If one connector does not work (maybe it is not available in this system?) Then I'm trying another.

Comment: 1. *Where does it say you have to use the domain name as the alias name?* This is what it says in your answer, and it is not correct.It is aiso not correct to state that you have to provide one. You don't. There is a default alias in `keytool`. Why you're telling him to use a domain-valued alias when all your examples use `tomcat` remains another mystery. 2. Randomly changing things isn't computer programming. It is guesswork.

Comment: English is not my native language. This is perhaps the cause of misunderstanding. It is indifferent to what alias will be. But it has to be. No mystery.
If I have a choice of 4 classes to choice for Input / Output and the first does not work then I check if other they work. This is practical programming. And if I have time and willingness, I am looking for a further cause. For example, I am looking to see if the class is available in libraries in the tomcat library path.

Comment: It doesn't 'have to be'. It has a default value. You are mistaken. I've already said that. Look it up. You can't just provide guesswork as an answer here. You have to explain.